# how to change image when scrolling webpage [html, javascript]

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i need to modify java script that will by changing fixed image.
In for example:
when page is loaded then image will by on right site. Next after scrolling down page image should be changed to next one for each e.g. 100px. Images need to by loaded from image list or something similar. 
I have found java script that make something similar to this. [Instead of creating images of numbers i need to load my own images]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body {
    height: 400%;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.show {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;
    right: 20px;
    background: lime;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<img class="show" alt="0" src="img0.jpg" />  
Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    

var lastI
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop()
   console.log(scrollTop)
   var i = (scrollTop / 10).toFixed(0)
   if (i !== lastI)
       $(".show").attr({
           "src": "img" + i + ".jpg",
           "alt": i
       })
   lastI = i
})

</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Update:09.11.2017
Ok, I manage this code to work. What should I do it was to setup right path to image files like in my case ("src": "test/" + i + ".jpg",) where my images are in "test" folder, and change names of images [1.jpg, 2.jpg and so on].

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: two things, is better to declare scrollTop out of scroll event, is allways the same and no need to re-calculate. And use Math.round or floor better to use fiexd. This last need to make a reflexion of us

Comment: How Instead of creating images of numbers load my own images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easyli change your image with Native scroll event, without using JQuery :

You can see how to use native scroll event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)

```
<body>
    <!-- This is an image with a 'show' id -->
    <img id="show" alt="0" src="img0.jpg" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* this capture the `scroll event`*/
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
            /* This generate a image name in case with scroll position  (ex img1.jpg) */
            let bgImage = 'img' + (window.scrollY / 10 ).toFixed(0) + '.jpg';
            /* This specify the path where are your images list */
            let bgImagePath = '../images/' + bgImage;

            /* This get your element (img) with id `show` and change this background image by the path include in `bgImagePath` variable */ 
            document.getElementById('show').style.backgroundImage = bgImagePath;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Native background image explain [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp)

Native getElementById explain [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

This sample of code do not use JQuery :) Just native Javascript : you van remove this lines in your code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

Hope I help you.

Comment: Ha, your link is in French. I thought I had forgotten how to read just then.

Comment: Sorry don't know javascript language (but i recognizing schema knowing python language). In this case dont know how to adopt this to my problem.

Comment: Hi ! Sorry for french link, I update this. And I update too my sample of code From yours :)

Comment: This still don't work, where to put list of images to load? This script change the background image in "show" frame and read "show" to get images??

Comment: Nope, This script change the background of element with id `show`, but the path, depend of your list of image ( maybe your image where in a `img` folder, you can change the path of img by `/img/img` + (window+scrollY /10).fixed(0) + '.jpg'.... that depend where are your images list related to this HTML page...

Comment: Doc Roms thanks for help, still You code don't work for my but i manage to modify original code thanks to you tips.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure, try this one:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
        $('.Classname').css("background-image","../images/image.png");
    } else {
        $('.Classname').css("background-image","none");
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks transparent to me, but maybe I do something wrong because it does not work

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi before using this you must import jquery into your code